# MongoDB | How to count a specific value of attribute and group by attribute in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Having collection with documents like the following one:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc027718da295b969e529ae"), 
    "emp_no" : 10001, 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "titles" : [
        {
            "title" : "Senior Engineer", 
            "dept_name" : "Development", 
            "from_date" : "1986-06-26", 
            "to_date" : "9999-01-01"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Staff", 
            "dept_name" : "Human Resources", 
            "from_date" : "1986-06-26", 
            "to_date" : "9999-01-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I count how many M's are working in certain department so I will have a result like *Development:874505*? 
I have another collection which consists of documents like:

```
//one document
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc026438da295b969e01893"), 
    "dept_no" : "d005", 
    "dept_name" : "Development", 
    "emp_no" : 10001, 
    "from_date" : "1986-06-26", 
    "to_date" : "9999-01-01"
}

//another document
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc026438da295b969e01894"), 
    "dept_no" : "d003", 
    "dept_name" : "Human Resources", 
    "emp_no" : 10001, 
    "from_date" : "1986-06-26", 
    "to_date" : "9999-01-01"
}
```

Maybe using this one can make the process easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I count how many M's are working in certain department so I
>   will have a result like *Development:874505*?

The Aggregation query:

The `$unwind` gets all the sub-document elements in the `titles` array. Then we match the ones by `gender` and `dept_name`. Finally, count them.
The `$group` stage makes sure that an employee working for the *same* department in two roles is counted as *one*.

```
var deptMatch = "Development";

db.emps.aggregate( [
  { $unwind: "$titles" },
  { $match: { gender: "M", "titles.dept_name": deptMatch } },
  { $group: { _id: "$emp_no" } },
  { $count: deptMatch }
] )
```

**NOTE**: In case there are lots of documents, I suggest you put the gender match before the unwind stage. You will deal with less number of documents in the following stages.

---

**[ EDIT ADD ]**

I used this sample data (removed some fields for brevity) to get the result of:

```
{ "Development" : 3 }
```

Collection `emps`'s documents:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "emp_no" : 10001, 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "titles" : [
        { "title" : "Senior Engineer",  "dept_name" : "Development" },
        { "title" : "Staff", "dept_name" : "Human Resources" }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : 2, 
    "emp_no" : 10002, 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "titles" : [
        { "dept_name" : "Development" }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : 3, 
    "emp_no" : 10009, 
    "gender" : "F", 
    "titles" : [
        { "dept_name" : "Procurement" }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 4, 
    "emp_no" : 10004, 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "titles" : [
        { "dept_name" : "HR" },
        { "dept_name" : "Procurement" }
    ]
}
{   "_id" : 5, 
    "emp_no" : 10012, 
    "gender" : "M", "titles" : [ 
        { "title" : "Staff", "dept_name" : "Development" }, 
        { "title" : "Senior Staff", "dept_name" : "Development" } 
    ] 
}
```

Comment: This kind of works but returns different value than my relational equivalent (returns 75517 but should be 51449). Maybe some of M's are double counted somehow? Like the person who has 2 titles in development (one regular and one senior) is counted for 2 instead of 1? He can't be employed in the same dept more than one time

Comment: It works fine. May be  the data is different than the one you had mentioned in the question post. Please take a closer look at the input data. Try with a sample of 5 to 10 documents and check the result.

Comment: I posted some sample data to run with the query. The query works fine.

Comment: It works almost fine :) - I took your data and add one more { "_id" : 6, "emp_no" : 10012, "gender" : "M", "titles" : [ { "title" : "Staff", "dept_name" : "Development" }, { "title" : "Senior Staff", "dept_name" : "Development" } ] } While for your data the result is 2 but if you add this one the result should be 3 but is 4

Comment: I changed the code and it works with your new data, also.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the **$count** operator. I encourage you to read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) here. And also the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#definition) of the method **aggregate** if you never used it before

Using the **first collection** :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "titles.title": "Senior Engineer",
      gender: "M"
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "Human Resources count"
  }
])
```

The output will be :

```
 {
    "Human Resources count": x
 }
```

Comment: The thing is there's no need to count every employee in HR, just the Males for example. How to add this condition?

Comment: @digitalis please try the updated answer, it should work

Comment: It does not :( I tried with _"titles.dept_name": "Development"_ as well but it's not working

Comment: @digitalis : IMO this or just .count() should suffice your requirement, maybe a minor data issue or an input issue might be causing a problem for you - but this is simple, Please do not use $unwind & $group stages for a normal count - these two are expensive stages in aggregation when not properly used with respective indexes plus on a whole collection (Even count can also be expensive on whole - if it really comes into picture then there can be aggregation + it's options) !!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query to count the number of objects with gender 'M' and working for a certain department.

```
db.col2.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "dept_no": "d005"}
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "col1",
            "localField": "emp_no",
            "foreignField": "emp_no",
            "as": "employees"
        }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": "$employees" } }
    },
    {
        "$match": { "gender": "M" }
    }, 
    {
        "$count": "m_count"
    }
])
```

col2 collection having the second set of documents and col1 is the one with the first document in the question.

Comment: It stucks on executing and can't finish :( the two collections does not have to be used together so If you have a solution without using one, maybe this might be easier?

Comment: Okay, the query uses both collections, doing a 'join' from one to the other. Maybe the query provided by @prasad_ will provide you the results. 

Wasn't sure if ```titles``` contains current information as opposed to historical information such as all titles ever held by an employee. If that is the case then it is an option to store gender in each document of the second collection. That'll make it a straightforward query on a single collection.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to try this, it should work for your case - considering document given in question :

```
db.yourFirstCollectionName.aggregate([{ $match: { gender: 'M', 'titles.dept_name': 'Development' } },
{ $count: 'totalNoOfEmployees' }])
```

**Result :**

```
{
    "totalNoOfEmployees" : 1
}
```

**Explanation :**

First stage in aggregation `$match` would get all the documents where `gender :m` && at least one object in `titles` array that has `title.dept_name : 'Development'`. `$count` would get us the count of documents being matched to this criteria, just simple output gives no.of employees.

Just in case if you think `aggregation` is not necessary, then try this through casual `.find()` :

```
db.yourFirstCollectionName.find({ gender: 'M', 'titles.dept_name': 'Development'}).count()
```

or even simpler with `.count()` :

```
db.yourFirstCollectionName.count({ gender: 'M', 'titles.dept_name': 'Development'})
```

These two would produce same result : `1`